# I get Play Console WearOS error java.lang.RuntimeException:

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, google-play-console

I uploaded my app to play store but on wear os I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.companyname.appname.App: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

I guess I should make the app only for mobile phones and tablets. How can it do this? Because it wasn't designed for WearOS.

It generates crashes and ANR error in Play console. (1 error)

Comment: Bump.  I get this too and seems to have started as soon as you target API 33 as recent email told us to do.  I feel like it's more a bug in their pre-launch reporting scripts as regular apps can't run on Wear OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Wear OS version of your app in Android Studio by selecting New Project from the File menu, and then on the screen with type of app (Phone and Tablet, Wear OS, Android TV, Automotive, Android Things), select Wear OS. Then continue with Blank Activity and hit Next.  Fill out the Configure Your Project screen and press Finish.

Then copy your app source code/artifacts to the corresponding files/elements of the new Wear OS app.  You will have to make the app workable on wearable devices--screen views, etc.  Then upload your app to your new release on Google Play.